# Selenium with expected conditions: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xyz/Documents/Projects/apartmentsearch/stanga.py", line 46, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME('sk-fading-circle spinner-container-3')))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

When running this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PHANTOMJS_PATH = './pjs/bin/phantomjs'

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(PHANTOMJS_PATH)
browser.get('REDACTED')

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME('sk-fading-circle spinner-container-3')))
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME('sk-fading-circle spinner-container-3')))

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())
```

Running python 2.7. Redacted website URL but it's working, I can load the page without the wait.

Code snippets online seem to indicate that code like this should be runnable. What am I missing? I would use breakpoints to figure it out but PyCharm isn't stopping on my breakpoints for some reason, which is something I'd also like to figure out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're specifying your locator wrong. It needs to be a tuple (or array) of `(By, selector_string)`

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sk-fading-circle 
spinner-container-3')))
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sk-fading-circle 
spinner-container-3')))
```

Also it looks like you're trying to use multiple classes for CLASS_NAME. I don't think that will work. You should try `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.sk-fading-circle.spinner-container-3')` instead